# percentages as independent variables and risks of multicollinearity

Tags: multicollinearity, percentage

I am working on a model in which I would have percentages among my independent variables. To be more specific, I would include in the model the variables that, together, would attain a 100 (say I want to explain Diet and the two variables I have are the share of apples and the share of pears..).

My question is: do I necessarily have a problem of multicollinearity or of too high correlation between my independent variables?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The world you have entered the world of compositional data analysis - enjoy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data

Answer (score 2):

Because your independent variables must necessarily sum to a constant, there is bound to be correlation amongst them, as they cannot vary independently. The situation is similar to the correlation of the residuals from a linear model. They are correlated because we are imposing that their sum is zero through the first order conditions of the OLS estimator. For just two-three variables that you are describing, I would expect quite high correlation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, i figured i would have had correlation since, yes, as you said, those vars are not independent the one from the other. The thing is that I sense that this may be a big issue for the result i may obtain. Right? Would it be too big an issue? Would it be less an issue if, say, i have three different shares that together amount to 100 but i just want to test the effect of two of these? My feeling is that i wouldn t have a problem with two. What do you think? Thanks again for your kind answer!